# How can I get a file's UbuntuOne URL from the terminal?

Tags: command-line, nautilus, bash, ubuntu-one, scripts

How can I get the UbuntuOne URL from a file in a bash script?

Here's what my script does so far:
I run the script via Nautilus Actions, and it requires one parameter and an URL in the clipboard. The parameter must be a FLAC file name.
The script checks that the URL in the clipboard is valid and also if the FLAC file is a valid FLAC file. It then extracts some of the tags and produce two HTML files. One containing information about the song, the other one adding a line in an ”index file” – a file with one line per song with links to the different HTML files and so on…

Anyway, to run the script properly right now I need to do the following:
1. In Nautilus, right click the file, then Ubuntu One → Publish
2. Right click the file again, then Ubuntu One → Copy URL (sometimes I need to press F5 first for this to work properly)
3. Right click the file again, then Nautilus Actions → FLAC tags to HTML
4. The script then asks for a comment via Yad (”Yet Another Dialog” – a fork of Zenity)

So, all I want to do at the moment, is to eliminate step 1 and 2. It would be nice if the script could do that for me. The file name and path should be enough information for the script, I think.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `u1sdtool` command line tool to interact with `ubuntuone-syncdaemon` from a script. The `--publish-file` and `--info` options should let you do what you need to do. You'll have to wait until the file is actually "published" before `--info` will include the URL to the public file, though.

Comment: **$ u1sdtool --publish-file "04. Mr. Moto.flac" 
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-client/ubuntuone/platform/tools/__init__.py:484: UnicodeWarning: Unicode equal comparison failed to convert both arguments to Unicode - interpreting them as being unequal
  success_filter=lambda info: info['path'] == path,**  
Then nothing more happens and I need to stop it with Ctrl+c…

Comment: Sorry for ugly comment. Couldn't make new lines as I could to the original post.

Comment: I think you need to pass the full path to the file.

Comment: Tried that too with the same result. Both ”/home/…/…/filename.flac” and ”./filename.flac”. It seemed to work somehow anyway; in Nautilus the file was actually published and I could click the Copy URL right click menu option.

Comment: Also, --publish-file is not mentioned in the man page…

Comment: I tried it again today and now it works, so maybe something was not working properly at UbuntuOne's side.